# Is it posible to change django form_class dynamically in view class?

Tags: django, forms, view

In my django app I need to have a different form for the different user role groups; I mean, at least two different forms. Is there any possible way to do so ?

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using a class-based view. All the creation/editing views are based on ModelFormMixin, which includes a [`get_form_class()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_class).

Comment: Daniel, indeed ! I am using the class-based view option. I am taking a look into this get_form_class() method and it looks fantastic, seems it´s gonna be really helpful. thanks a lot for your help.